# UISegmentedControl: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on ValueChanged handler

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to use in my application UISegmentedControl, to make something similar to TabBar component in windows. And I use ValueChanged Handler:

```
- (IBAction)tabBarChange:(id)sender{
    int pageId = tabBar.selectedSegmentIndex;
    // [self switchPage:pageId];
}
```

`switchPage` is empty function now, no one line of code written.

But, when taping on SegmentedControl, EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception appears.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Is this action - (IBAction)tabBarChange:(id)sender connected to the UISegmentControl in the XIB

Comment: When you try to use any of the ivars or properties of your view controller, you're getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Sounds like your view controller might have been released. How did you transition to this view controller? Hopefully not by doing an `addSubview`, but rather via `presentViewController` or `pushViewController`. Anyway, if you're getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` for any ivar or property, then show us how you transitioned to this view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i understand that this method crashed:

```
- (IBAction)tabBarChange:(id)sender {
    [self switchPage:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

If you try to make some test function without passing any argument, will it work, for example:

```
- (IBAction)tabBarChange:(id)sender {
    [self testFunction];
}

- (void) testFunction {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is tabBar really defined in that function? Should it not be:

```
int pageId = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

Tim

Comment: It is still not working. if I chage to - (IBAction)tabBarChange:(id)sender{
    //int pageId = tabBar.selectedSegmentIndex;
    int pageId = 0;
    [self switchPage:pageId];
}
EXC_BAD_ACCESS also appears